# Meta property al:web:should_fallback on web content shared on Facebook Native App is no longer respected

Tags: facebook, meta-tags, applinks

It was working before as it should be: Clicking on my website url from facebook native app (shared post) redirects to the App store when my native app is not installed. If my native app is installed, it opens the url in my app.

I have all the required meta as well as this one:

```
<meta property="al:web:should_fallback" content="false" />
```

Suddenly, redirecting to the app store when my native app is not installed stopped working.

Does Facebook no longer support `al:web:should_fallback` meta tag?

Everything was working fine!

Answer (score 0):

I want to let you know that the issue is now fixed. It was a bug on Facebook object platform. I submitted a bug report on the Facebook bug tracker and they reproduced the problem and fixed it.